# Why now i can't do android:id="@+idLayouName/text"?

Tags: android, eclipse

The error eclipse puts is :

ID definitions *must* be of the form @+id/name; try using"@+id/ErrorDialog_text"

the code:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+idErrorDialog/text"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/error_dialog_server_error"
    android:textColor="@color/purple_chart_points"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

I have all my layout like this and I don't want to change them all. An I prefer to do it like I did it before it is easier for me.

Comment: You say, that you have all your id-definitions like this `android:id="@+idXYZ/ABC"`??? This is and was always syntactically wrong. How did you get that? Was that code ever running?

Comment: Yes this works perfectly since yesterday when I update the android tools. I like a lot because when I referring to it  like R.idErrorDialog.text, the eclipse auto complete works better

Comment: Seems like there was an "undocumented feature" which is fixed now. Sorry to say that, but I see no other way then changing to the "correct" way.

Answer (score 1):

The "@+id" part has to be followed with a "/". This is just a convention for the system to recognize that the part after the "/" is the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

There is one missing `/` in your id.

Answer (score 0):

Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree.

The syntax for an ID, inside an XML tag is:

```
 android:id="@+id/ErrorDialogtext" // after @+id you need /
```

When you initialize your textview

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ErrorDialogtext);
 // referring to the resource in R.java
```

The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

You can your project R.java.Once you add a resource in your xml file and save there is automatic entry in R.java.

```
 public static final class id {
      public static final int ErrorDialogtext=0x7f080007; 
      // value in your case might be different
      // do not modify this 
 }
```

You can also have this

```
     android:id="@android:id/empty" // referring to the id in the android framework
```

For more info check the topic under id in the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an ID attribute is

> android:id="@+id/name"

So, In the eclipse it is showing the error.
Use

> android:id = "@+id/ErrorDialog_text"

Refer the below link for more about ID attribute
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

ID's like those aren't correct. It was a bug that we allowed it earlier.

For more info, see:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/60766/